# Getting 404 Error on Node-Express Prometheus metrics endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, histogram, prometheus, metrics

I have a Node-Express API set up to expose prometheus metrics but the metrics endpoint is throwing 404 error :

```
nodemon index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Morgan enabled ...
Listening at port 3000
(node:25264) [DEP0152] DeprecationWarning: Custom PerformanceEntry accessors are deprecated. Please use the detail property.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Logging ...
GET /metrics 404 146 - 3.360 ms
Logging ...
GET /metrics 404 146 - 1.581 ms
Logging ...
```

When I navigate to http://localhost:3000/swagger-stats/metrics I get a bunch of metrics including the 404 error calls. It appears as if the prom-client library itself comes pre-packaged with a histogram but the only difference to my custom histogram is the bucket sizes and metric name:

```
# HELP api_request_duration_milliseconds API 

requests duration
# TYPE api_request_duration_milliseconds histogram
api_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{le="5",method="GET",path="/metrics",code="404"} 4
api_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{le="10",method="GET",path="/metrics",code="404"} 8
api_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{le="25",method="GET",path="/metrics",code="404"} 9
api_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{le="50",method="GET",path="/metrics",code="404"} 9
api_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{le="100",method="GET",path="/metrics",code="404"} 9
api_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{le="250",method="GET",path="/metrics",code="404"} 9
```

This is how I have defined my custom histogram :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const home = require('./routes/home')
const logger = require('./middleware/logger');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const facebook = require('./routes/facebook');
var swStats = require('swagger-stats');
const promClient = require('prom-client');

promClient.collectDefaultMetrics();
app.use(swStats.getMiddleware());
const histogram = new promClient.Histogram({
  name: 'response_duration_seconds',
  help: 'The duration in seconds between the response to a request',
  labelNames: ['status_code', 'method', 'path'],
  buckets: [0.02, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2.5, 5, 10],
});
//histogram.zero({ method: 'GET' });
//histogram.zero({ method: 'POST' });
histogram.observe(10); 
app.use(home);
app.use(facebook);
app.use(logger);
```

For context my API is already working as expected and I can query data for this endpoint :

```
router.get('/api/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
 const post = findPost(parseInt(req.params.id));
 if(!post) return res.status(404).send(`Post with id ${req.params.id} was not found`);
 res.send(post);
 });
```

on ***http://localhost:3000/api/posts/1***

**EXPECTED**
When I query http://localhost:3000/metrics I expect some output like this :

```
# HELP request_duration_seconds The duration in 

seconds between the response to a request.
# TYPE request_duration_seconds histogram
request_duration_seconds_sum{status_code="200",method="GET",path="/api/posts/"} 0.0594246
request_duration_seconds_count{status_code="200",method="GET",path="/api/posts/"} 5
request_duration_seconds_bucket{status_code="200",method="GET",path="/api/posts/",le="0.01"} 4
request_duration_seconds_bucket{status_code="200",method="GET",path="/api/posts/",le="0.025"} 4
request_duration_seconds_bucket{status_code="200",method="GET",path="/api/posts/",le="0.05"} 4
request_duration_seconds_bucket{status_code="200",method="GET",path="/api/posts/",le="0.1"} 5
request_duration_seconds_bucket{status_code="200",method="GET",path="/api/posts/",le="0.25"} 5
request_duration_seconds_bucket{status_code="200",method="GET",path="/api/posts/",le="0.5"}
```

According to the documentation *"Metrics with labels can not be exported before they have been observed at least once since the possible label values are not known before they're observed.This can be solved by explicitly zeroing all expected label values"*

However when I try to update my histogram like this :

```
const histogram = new promClient.Histogram({


 name: 'response_duration_seconds',
  help: 'The duration in seconds between the response to a request',
  labelNames: ['status_code', 'method', 'path'],
  buckets: [0.02, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2.5, 5, 10],
});
histogram.zero({ method: 'GET' });
histogram.zero({ method: 'POST' });
histogram.observe(10);
```

I get an error :

```
histogram.zero({ method: 'GET' });
      ^
TypeError: histogram.zero is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\index.js:17:11)     
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.14.1
```

What am I missing ?

I am also not sure what value I am supposed to pass to the line : histogram.observe(10);

NB : I am using the prom-client for this [Project](https://github.com/siimon/prom-client?ref=morioh.com&utm_source=morioh.com#default-metrics)